# Is there any way to change datepicker border line colour in xamarin

Tags: xamarin

When displaying datepicker in XAML page bottom borderline color is black. I want to change this color to white. How to solve this problem. Is there any custom renderer to set the bottom borderline color. I am using absolute layout in my XAML page. By default when displaying datepicker on my page the date with black bottom borderline color. I just want to change to white color.

Answer (score 0):

I posted an answer yesterday for another user who wanted to change the bottom line color of a text view. You can most likely do it the same way with a custom DatePicker; simply change the background to the xml resource in your custom renderer.

See here:
[How can i change editor bottom border line color using custom renderer in xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48561265/how-can-i-change-editor-bottom-border-line-color-using-custom-renderer-in-xamari/48561716#48561716)

Just change the `color` values in the XML code to `color="white"`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an XML file in drawable folder and add this styling. You can customize it according to the color you want.
Add this file to style of datepicker, Resource.Style.datepicker.

```
<style name="datepicker" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/clrDatePrimary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/clrDatePrimaryDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/clrDateAccent</item>
</style>
```